# Find the target in the mailbox

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

How to check the temporary mailbox when it finds the target the script stops automatically
the problem if the target is found after two minutes the code does not stop
I want to check the temporary mailbox every minute and when it finds the target the code stops.

```
import requests , json, re,random,string,time,warnings
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
warnings.simplefilter('ignore',InsecureRequestWarning)
s = requests.Session()
jsdata= adress email

def get_clipmails():
       html_data=s.get(jsdata).text 
       if "IPTV" in html_data:
            print("Target Found !!!")
            regx = '''M3U PLAYLIST URL:.*?&lt;a href=(.*?)&quot;&gt;'''
            link = "'"+re.findall(regx, html_data, re.M)[0].replace('&quot;','').replace('amp;amp;','').encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')+"'"    
       elif not "IPTV" in html_data: 
           time.sleep(60)                                                 
           html_data=s.get(jsdata).text
           regx = '''M3U PLAYLIST URL:.*?&lt;a href=(.*?)&quot;&gt;'''
           link = "'"+re.findall(regx, html_data, re.M)[0].replace('&quot;','').replace('amp;amp;','').encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')+"'"    
           print("link :", link)
       elif not "IPTV" in html_data: 
           time.sleep(60)                                                 
           html_data=s.get(jsdata).text
           regx = '''M3U PLAYLIST URL:.*?&lt;a href=(.*?)&quot;&gt;'''
           link = "'"+re.findall(regx, html_data, re.M)[0].replace('&quot;','').replace('amp;amp;','').encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')+"'"    
           print("link :", link)
       elif not "IPTV" in html_data: 
           time.sleep(60)                                                 
           html_data=s.get(jsdata).text
           regx = '''M3U PLAYLIST URL:.*?&lt;a href=(.*?)&quot;&gt;'''
           link = "'"+re.findall(regx, html_data, re.M)[0].replace('&quot;','').replace('amp;amp;','').encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')+"'"    
           print("link :", link)
       elif not "IPTV" in html_data: 
           time.sleep(60)                                                 
           html_data=s.get(jsdata).text
           regx = '''M3U PLAYLIST URL:.*?&lt;a href=(.*?)&quot;&gt;'''
           link = "'"+re.findall(regx, html_data, re.M)[0].replace('&quot;','').replace('amp;amp;','').encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')+"'"    
           print("link :", link)
```